# Disable running a program in Linux and Windows

Tags: java, linux, winapi, java-native-interface, hook

I am building a Computer Adaptive Test in Java[Swing] and want to disable running other programs in the background until the test finishes(or the user quits). This is to prevent candidates taking the test from cheating in the test.

My question is, how to go about it? How can I stop creation of new task or prevention of user from interacting with other programs?

My homework before asking this question was: 
1. I could use JNI and call SetForegroundWindow(HWND) function on windows. What are its equivalents in Linux?

1. Disable Keyboard completely using SetWindowsHookEx() function with a global LOWLEVEL KEYBOARD HOOK PROC. Equivalents in Linux?

Apologies if this question has been answered before --

Comment: But the candidates can still use another device (smartphone, tablet) to cheat instead of the computer they're passing the test on, can't they?

Comment: Well cellphones/tablets/smartphones are NOT allowed into the laboratory :-). Just that we didn't get the perms to install cameras in the lab. :-( and there are just two "monitors" monitoring the test.

Comment: Without native libraries, your Java code has no direct access to system events in way to block them. The JVM gets the events from the system and then your code gets them. Therefore, your code cannot disable the use of the keyboard. On Linux you can enumerate through the running processes in the background and issue a kill -9 command to them using processbuilder.

Comment: It may be worth splitting this into seperate questions for Linux and Windows as they will have VERY different answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know how to stop someone from changing focus you could track the [focus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#trackingFocus), and detect when your GUI loses focus. You could even take some timing measurements so that, say 5 seconds is OK but 30 is not.

Answer (score 1):

How can I stop creation of new task or prevention of user from interacting with other programs

The above statement should not be allowed by the operating system, and i think you should gracefully warn the user not to start new tasks and interract with existing ones.

however, if you insist, you should consider writing some code acting like password protected screen saver, ofcourse not asking for a password.

Comment: i agree it shouldn't allow(easy to create nuisance to the user). I have seen programs like that at Alienware stores which showcase the computer's features, but do not allow task switching(alt+tab is disabled and the likes). I want to implement EXACTLY like that.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can make use of another [desktop session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (The same thing the Windows Vista and 7 UAC prompt uses by default).

This allows you to run your process with no way (for the user) of interacting with the rest of the desktop but be very careful to make sure you switch back before exiting otherwise they'll be stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Um I think I found a work around for this: (I should have thought about it in a simpler way).

I can implement WindowFocusListener to my frame and if the person cheats an ALARM will go off and alert the monitors.

Thanks everybody. :-)